# In caldav how to report time-range older than 1 year

Tags: xml, request, caldav

I'm trying to report event etag in caldav filtering by time-range. All work fine expect for time-range older than 1 year. 
I always get the message: Time-range value too far in the past. Must be on or after 20190430

Here is the request:

```
<c:calendar-query xmlns:A='DAV:' xmlns:c='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
    <A:prop>
        <A:getetag/>
    </A:prop>
    <c:filter>
        <c:comp-filter name='VCALENDAR'>
            <c:comp-filter name='VEVENT'>
                    <c:time-range start='20190424T184806Z' end='20190425T184806Z'/>
            </c:comp-filter>
        </c:comp-filter>
    </c:filter>
</c:calendar-query>";
```

and the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 16:48:06 GMT Server: Twisted/13.2.0 TwistedWeb/9.0.0 Content-Length: 289 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800 Content-Type: text/xml DAV: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-availability, inbox-availability, calendar-proxy, calendarserver-private-events, calendarserver-private-comments, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-sharing-no-scheduling, calendar-query-extended, calendar-default-alarms, calendar-managed-attachments, calendarserver-partstat-changes, calendar-no-timezone, calendarserver-recurrence-split, extended-mkcol, calendarserver-principal-property-search, calendarserver-principal-search, calendarserver-home-sync MS-Author-Via: DAV Vary: User-Agent Connection: close Time-range value too far in the past. Must be on or after 20190430.
```

How can I report event older than 1 year?

Comment: I've never seen that happen and according to RFC infinity is assumed when start/end missing. "If either the"start" or "end" attribute is not specified in the CALDAV:time-range XML element, assume "-infinity" and "+infinity" as theirvalue, respectively." What caldav server are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS server 10.10 build in Caldav.

Comment: When I don't provide start date, it assume -infinity as start date and work fine. But when I provide a date older than 1 year, I always get then same error.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I gathered, I can see your caldav server is using some sort of Twisted Caldav server (never used it, never even used MacOS builtin caldav server). I found this [archived repo](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver) of what seems to be implementation for this caldav server. In that repo I found the `Exception` that you provided, [here](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/master/twistedcaldav/method/report_calendar_query.py#L282):

```py
except TimeRangeLowerLimit, e:
    raise HTTPError(ErrorResponse(
        responsecode.FORBIDDEN,
        caldavxml.MinDateTime(),
        "Time-range value too far in the past. Must be on or after %s." % (str(e.limit),)(str(e.limit),)
```

Looking at the `TimeRangeLowerLimit Exception` implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/13c706b985fb728b9aab42dc0fef85aae21921c3/txdav/caldav/icalendarstore.py#L815):

```py
class TimeRangeLowerLimit(Exception):
    """
    A request for time-range information too far in the past cannot be satisfied.
    """

    def __init__(self, lowerLimit):
        self.limit = lowerLimit
```

It seems like there actually is a limit set. Digging deeper to `MinDateTime` class [here](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/13c706b985fb728b9aab42dc0fef85aae21921c3/twistedcaldav/caldavxml.py#L369):

```py
class MinDateTime (CalDAVTextElement):
    """
    Specifies restrictions on a calendar collection.
    (CalDAV-access, RFC 4791 section 5.2.6)
    """
    name = "min-date-time"
    hidden = True
    protected = True
```

It points to the section [5.2.6 in RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-5.2.6), which says:

> Name:  min-date-time
>
> Namespace:  urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav
>
> Purpose:  Provides a DATE-TIME value indicating the earliest date and
> time (in UTC) that the server is willing to accept for any DATE or
> DATE-TIME value in a calendar object resource stored in a calendar
> collection.

I always thought about this as an input limit though, not a search (report) limit, which confuses me a lot. Going back to the implementation, the exception is being thrown from [here](https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/blob/13c706b985fb728b9aab42dc0fef85aae21921c3/txdav/caldav/datastore/sql.py#L1765):

```py
# Determine if the start date is too early for the restricted range we
# are applying. If it is today or later we don't need to worry about truncation
# in the past.
minDate, _ignore_isEndDate = filter.getmintimerange()
if minDate >= today:
    minDate = None
if minDate is not None and config.FreeBusyIndexLowerLimitDays:
    truncateLowerLimit = today - Duration(days=config.FreeBusyIndexLowerLimitDays)
    if minDate < truncateLowerLimit:
        raise TimeRangeLowerLimit(truncateLowerLimit)
```

Looking at the condition `if minDate is not None and config.FreeBusyIndexLowerLimitDays:`, as you want to use `minDate` (aka start of the `time-range`), the only possible solution seems to be to somehow set a different `FreeBusyIndexLowerLimitDays` in the config.

I've never seen this problem with other caldav implementations (I mainly use Sabre), so I can't help you more than this unfortunately.